# Carrierwave Multiple File Upload + No implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

Trying to get Carrierwave multiple file uploads working.  I'm following the documentation on the homepage.  When I try to upload a file or multiple, I get an `no implicit conversion of nil to string`

That error is coming from this method in the Carrierwave gem found in `uploaders/cache.rb`

```
def workfile_path(for_file=original_filename)
    File.join(CarrierWave.tmp_path, @cache_id, version_name.to_s, for_file)
 end
```

The issue is that the original_file is nil.  I've tried to trace the issue but can't find where the issue is really beginning.  One thing that is odd is that I am following some source code from this repo

`https://github.com/bobintornado/sample-gallery-app-with-carrierwave`

The sample app is working and you can do multiple uploads.  The difference though is that when `cache!` method is called the `new_file` is an `Array` where in sample app that's working it's `Http::UploadedFile`

Here's the cache method

```
  def cache!(new_file = sanitized_file)
    new_file = CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.new(new_file)
    return if new_file.empty?

    raise CarrierWave::FormNotMultipart if new_file.is_path? && ensure_multipart_form

    self.cache_id = CarrierWave.generate_cache_id unless cache_id

    @filename = new_file.filename
    self.original_filename = new_file.filename

    begin
      # first, create a workfile on which we perform processings
      if move_to_cache
        @file = new_file.move_to(File.expand_path(workfile_path, root), permissions, directory_permissions)
      else
        @file = new_file.copy_to(File.expand_path(workfile_path, root), permissions, directory_permissions)
      end

      with_callbacks(:cache, @file) do
        @file = cache_storage.cache!(@file)
      end
    ensure
      FileUtils.rm_rf(workfile_path(''))
    end
  end
```

Here are my initial params

```
"coach"=>{"name"=>"ben", "title"=>"ceo", "description"=>"head dude",
"photos"=>[
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc9a5235c78 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/sb/t6rry5j928l3sy96nkhy9f840000gn/T/RackMultipart20160113-67635-avg8ef.jpg>, @original_filename="benn-1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"coach[photos][]\"; filename=\"benn-1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc9a5235c50 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/sb/t6rry5j928l3sy96nkhy9f840000gn/T/RackMultipart20160113-67635-r8bdxp.jpg>, @original_filename="benn-2.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"coach[photos][]\"; filename=\"benn-2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't terribly helpful, but I burned my current working branch and started from the beginning and now everything is working.  Not sure what I did differently.  If you're running into the same issue I recommend starting over and following this tutorial:

[Multiple-Images-Uploading-With-CarrierWave-and-PostgreSQL-Array](http://bobintornado.github.io/rails/2015/12/29/Multiple-Images-Uploading-With-CarrierWave-and-PostgreSQL-Array.html)